# scala spark - `not found: value when`

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am trying use a `withColumn` & `WHEN` statement in my spark package. But when I am trying execute the below statement, I get an error`not found: value when`. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("status", when("count > 0", "Fulfilled")).select("pak", "id", "status")
```

Comment: Look up how to use a udf

Comment: can u add more information.What u want?

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate on @AlbertoBonsanto . This is a common mistake : "forgotten imports".

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I've answered a very similar question last week.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Found the solution. It worked when I added the below import statement.

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._